How to bring variables from one activity to another: Returning to MainActivity using activityResultLauncher
I'm really new to android dev, and am self-taught (I know, sorry...) I'm working in Java, and am trying to write an app to record scores etc for netball games.
My roadblock at the moment is that i have a secondary activity (playerlist.java) in which i want to enter the team info (player names and positions), and then send that back to the MainActivity. I'm using arraylists to do this (aiming to do it for 3 teams to start).
The biggest problem that I'm having is that when the arraylist comes back into the MainActivity, it does not get saved/overwrite the initial values. It seems like that line does not run. What am I missing? The toast message comes up with the new (changed) value for the first player, but when click the repurposed "Setup" button, the old value comes up, and when i go back into the playerlist, the old values are still there.
You can see below that I've declared the ArrayList before the onCreate (have tried both public and private), and have initialised and populated the ArrayList inside the onCreate.
I'm using the "new" ActivityResultLauncher, and all seems to be (mostly) good in passing the ArrayList to playerlist activity. I say "mostly" because it seems like it only happens the 2nd time i click the PlayerList button. But that's a secondary issue.
So in the playerlist activity, i change players names, and then hit a save and return button, and this seems to successfully pass the modified arraylist back to the MainActivity.  And toast messages return the modified array data, but thereafter, the array is as per original.
I have repurposed another button on the MainActivity to poll the array, so that i can see via a toast what the value is.
What am I missing? I can add the code from playerlist.java if you need it too.
(I've removed a bunch of code that's irrelevant to this question.)
package com.example.keepingscore_netball;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
/*import static com.example.keepingscore_netball.setup.TEAM_NAME;*/
import static java.util.Collections.addAll;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView tvScore1, tvScore2, tvTimer,tvGameTitle, tvQuarterNum;
    public EditText etTeam1,etTeam2;
    public int iScore1, iScore2, iGS1, iGA1, iGS2, iGA2, iGS1M, iGA1M, iGS2M, iGA2M, iNumPers,iPerDuration,iPerNum,iLength;
    public long TimeMultiplier;
    public String sScore1, timeFormatted,sTeam1,sTeam2,sAllStats, StatsFileName,filePath, sLastAction, sCentrePass,sInGameTime,sCurrMode;

    /*We will be able to follow 3 teams (eventually).
    Each team will have an array; Pos(0) will be the team name, next 10 posns will be player names.
    I'll start with 3 teams, then expand. */
    public Boolean bTimerRunning, bDebugMode;
    public Button btnShowStats, btnPlayerList, btnSetup, btnBestOnCourt, btnLoadSaved,btnUndo,btnGameMode;
    public Button btnGS1,btnGA1,btnGS1M,btnGA1M,btnGS2,btnGA2,btnGS2M,btnGA2M; /*For enabling and disabling*/
    public SharedPreferences spSavedValues;
    public CountDownTimer cdTimer,cdEndofPeriodTimer;
    public StringBuilder sAllActions;

    public ArrayList<String> sOurTeam1,sOurTeam2,sOurTeam3;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

// stuff
        tvGameTitle=findViewById(R.id.GameTitle);
// stuff
        etTeam1=findViewById(R.id.T1Name);
        etTeam2=findViewById(R.id.T2Name);
    etTeam1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String sTempTitle = s + " vs " + etTeam2.getText().toString();
                tvGameTitle.setText(sTempTitle);
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
        etTeam2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String sTempTitle = etTeam1.getText().toString() + " vs " + s;
                tvGameTitle.setText(sTempTitle);
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
// stuff
        sOurTeam1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        sOurTeam2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        sOurTeam3 = new ArrayList<String>();


        if (sOurTeam1.size()<1 ){
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                sOurTeam1.add("");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                sOurTeam1.set (i,"Player _"+i);
            }
        }
        if (sOurTeam2.size()<1 ){
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                sOurTeam2.add("");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                sOurTeam2.set (i,"Player_"+i);
            }
        }
        if (sOurTeam3.size()<1 ){
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                sOurTeam3.add("");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                sOurTeam3.set (i,"Player_"+i);
            }
        }

// stuff

        sAllActions = new StringBuilder(0);

// stuff
        btnPlayerList =findViewById(R.id.PlayerList);
        btnPlayerList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                ShowPlayerList();
            }
            /*ToDo Enable setup and Playerlist and Best on Court functionality and buttons*/
        });
        btnSetup= findViewById(R.id.Settings);
        btnSetup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //ShowSetupScreen();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sOurTeam1.get(1), LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Test line for playerlist data
            }
        });
// stuff

        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode()== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                            Intent data=result.getData();
                            if (data!=null) {
                                sOurTeam1.clear();sOurTeam2.clear();sOurTeam3.clear();
                                sTeam1=data.getStringExtra("Team1Name");
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sTeam1, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                etTeam1.setText(sTeam1);
                                tvGameTitle.setText(sTeam1);
                                sOurTeam1.addAll(data.getStringArrayListExtra("OurTeam1"));
                                sOurTeam1 = data.getStringArrayListExtra("OurTeam1");
                                sOurTeam2 = data.getStringArrayListExtra("OurTeam2");
                                sOurTeam3 = data.getStringArrayListExtra("OurTeam3");
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sOurTeam1.get(1), LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //This works correctly, and shows the new information
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Null data", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    private void ShowSetupScreen() {
    }
    private void ShowPlayerList() {
        Intent intentChange = new Intent(MainActivity.this, playerlist.class);
        intentChange.putExtra("Team1Name",sTeam1);
        intentChange.putStringArrayListExtra("OurTeam1",sOurTeam1);
        intentChange.putStringArrayListExtra("OurTeam2",sOurTeam2);
        intentChange.putStringArrayListExtra("OurTeam3",sOurTeam3);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sOurTeam1.get(1), LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        activityResultLauncher.launch(intentChange);
    }
// stuff below - Bunch of public routines to record points, vibrate, game timer, collate and show stats etc.
    public void ResetGame(View view) {
    }


I took a quick look at your app and, in my opinion, the most suitable approach is to use fragments instead of an additional activity. See https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments
